# How can I parse a String[] to an int[] in java?

Tags: string, casting, int

I have the code:

```
String s = "a,b,c,d,e";
int[] i = s.split(",");
```

but this cast is not avaiable.

Some one can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You must loop over each element in the array and cast them one by one.

Like this:

```
String s = "a,b,c,d,e";
String[] strings = s.split(",");
int[] i = new int[strings.length];
for(int j = 0; j < strings.length; j++)
{
    i[j] = Integer.parseInt(strings[j]);            
}
```

Note that this code will crash, since the elements in the string-array aren't integers.

Answer (score 0):

Java is [strongly-typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing) which means it won't allow you to cast between incompatible types.  In order to convert between integers and strings, you need to explicitly do the conversion.  `Integer.parseInt` can convert a string to an integer.  So you will need to loop through your array and convert each integer to a string individually.

```
String[] strings = "a,b,c,d,e".split(",");
int parsedIntegers[] = new int[strings.length];
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    parsedIntegers[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
}
```