# Java how to parse integers with spaces

Tags: java

I have a string, actually user put in console next string :

`10 20 30 40 50`

how i can parse it to `int[]` ?

I tried to use `Integer.parseInt(String s);` and parse string with `String.indexOf(char c)` but i think it's too awful solution.

Comment: can u paste the stact trace or some error or results

Comment: I think You are Asking some Straight method right?

Comment: no error. I just looking for a solutions..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse a String\[\] to an int\[\] in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143608/how-can-i-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Comment: @ambarox no Evan Knowless answer my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string to int array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027278/split-string-to-int-array)

Comment: @ambarox Honestly, I'd vote that one as a retro duplicate of this one; Evan's answer is much better than any of the answers there.

Comment: Yes of Course. I also upvoted. :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a `Scanner` and `.nextInt()`, or you could use the `.split()` command on the String to split it into an array of Strings and parse them separately.

For example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(yourString);
ArrayList<Integer> myInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
  myInts.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

For the `split`:

```
String[] intParts = yourString.split("\\s+");
ArrayList<Integer> myInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (String intPart : intParts) {
  myInts.add(Integer.parseInt(intPart));
}
```

Comment: You can give me example how to do that?

Comment: @deathember The documentation for [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) have the examples you are looking for.

Comment: I've added examples for both.

Comment: @EvanKnowles Don't forget the parameter to `split()`. `split(" ")` is straightforward, and `split("\\s+")` is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

1. Split the String, using the [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method with the delimiter space.
2. For each element in the `String[]`, parse it into an `int` using `Integer.parseInt()` and add them to your `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String split[] = string.split(" ")
```

is will generate an array of string then you can parse the array to int.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string then parse the integers like the following function:

```
int[] parseInts(String s){
    String[] sNums = s.split(" ");
    int[] nums = new int[sNums.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < sNums.length; i++){
        nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(sNums[i);
    }
    return nums;
}
```